# How to pull the finalUri property from an async image lookup result?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In windows phone 7 I'm doing a simple async lookup to find an image by uri and set the returned binary as the source for an image control.

```
public object SetImageFromUri(string uri)
{
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
    wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uri), wc);

    return null;
}

void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
    {
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(e.Result);

            //e.Result has a property in the memory stream labeled finalUri
            //someImageControl.Source = image;

    }
}
```

My question is- how can I pull out the final uri property from the e.Result so I can see what image control it's associated with

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the WebClient through as the second parameter, pass the Uri (or some other piece of usefule state information)

```
wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uri), uri);
```

You can then access this in your callback

```
var uri = (string)e.UserState;
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to specific restrictions implemented in the Reflection mechanism, you cannot access internal content from sandboxed code. Ultimately, you would want to use something like this:

```
FieldInfo f = e.Result.GetType().GetField("_finalUri", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance);
Uri n = (Uri)f.GetValue(e.Result);
```

However, this will cause a `FieldAccessException`. If you are not using a redirect URI, then you can simply reuse the parameter that is initially passed to your method. If not, you need to check HttpWebRequest and follow the [idea I outlined a couple of days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900024/get-current-uri-when-redirected-in-webclient-wp7/6905427#6905427).

Answer (score 1):

You could also just bind directly to the Image, and use the [LowProfileImageLoader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx), to avoid it blocking the UI thread during the load. (Remember to set a FallBack image)

Comment: Excellent -but how can I set a fall back image using this library?

Comment: Set it as a default value for the property you're binding. (It throws a exception if you bind to a null value)